# How can I print only lines that are immediately preceeded by an empty line in a file using sed?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file with the following structure:

```
bla1
bla2

bla3
bla4

bla5
```

So you can see that some lines of text are preceeded by an empty line.

I understand that sed has the concept of two buffers, a pattern space buffer and a hold space buffer, so I'm guessing these need to come in to play here, but I'm unclear how to specify them to accomplish what I need.

In my contrived example above, I'd expect to see the following lines outputted:

```
bla3
bla5
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your work so far in your question. You'll get the best help by showing us the code you're working on, the results you expected and the results you got.

Answer (score 2):

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual lines, that is all. Any time you start talking about buffers or doing anything related to multi-lines comparisons you're using the wrong tool.

You could do this with awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'NR>1{print $1}' file
bla3
bla5
```

but it would fail to print the first non-empty line if the first line(s) in the file were empty so this may be what you want if you want lines of all space chars considered to be empty lines:

```
$ awk 'NF && !p{print} {p=NF}' file
bla3
bla5
```

and this otherwise:

```
$ awk '($0!="") && (p==""){print} {p=$0}' file
bla3
bla5
```

All of the above will work even if there are multiple empty lines preceding any given non-empty line.

To see the difference between the 3 approaches (which you won't see given the sample input in the question):

```
PS1> printf '\nfoo\n      \nbar\n\netc\n' | cat -E
$
foo$
      $
bar$
$
etc$

PS1> printf '\nfoo\n      \nbar\n\netc\n' | awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'NR>1{print $1}'
etc

PS1> printf '\nfoo\n      \nbar\n\netc\n' | awk 'NF && !p{print} {p=NF}'
foo
bar
etc

PS1> printf '\nfoo\n      \nbar\n\netc\n' | awk '($0!="") && (p==""){print} {p=$0}'
foo
etc
```

Comment: This is the only solution which works in all cases under the assumption that empty lines should not be printed if they are preceeded by an empty line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the hold buffer easily to print the line before the blank like this:

```
sed -n -e '/^$/{x; p;}' -e h input
```

But I don't see an easy way to use it for your use case.  For your case, instead of using the hold buffer, you could do:

```
sed -n -e '/^$/ba' -e d -e :a -e n -e p input
```

But I would do this with `awk`.

```
awk 'NR!=1{print $1}' RS= FS=\\n input-file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'p;{p=/^$/}' file
```

above command does these for each line:

1. if `p` is `1`, print line;
2. if line is empty, set `p` to `1`.

if lines consisting of one or more spaces are also considered empty:

```
awk 'p;{p=!NF}' file
```

---

to print non-empty lines each coming right after an empty line, you can use this:

```
awk 'p*!(p=/^$/)' file
```

1. if `p` is `1` and this line is not empty (`1*!(0) = 1*1 = 1`), print this line;
2. otherwise (`1*!(1) = 1*0 = 0`, `0*anything = 0`), don't print anything.

note that this one may not work with all awks, a portable version of this would look like:

```
awk 'p*(/./);{p=/^$/}' file
```

if lines consisting of one or more spaces are also considered empty:

```
awk 'p*NF;{p=!NF}' file
```

---

see them online [here](https://ideone.com/zhuhft), and [here](https://ideone.com/XzYMQ5).

Answer (score 0):

If sed/awk is not mandatory, you can do it with grep:

```
grep -A 1 '^$' input.txt  | grep -v -E '^$|--'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to match a range of lines and do sub-matches inside the matches, like so:

```
# - use the "-n" option to omit printing of lines
# - match lines between a blank line (/^$/) and a non-blank one (/^./),
#   then print only the line that contains at least a character,
#   i.e, the non-blank line.
sed -ne '
/^$/,/^./ {
    /^./{ p; }
}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

tested by gnu sed, your data in 'a':

```
$ sed -nE '/^$/{N;s/\n(.+)/\1/p}' a
bla3
bla5
```

add -i option precedes -n to real editing